# Apply "hspace" to only one side

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have applied hspace attribute to my image tag but it adds margin to both left and right hand side. Is there a way to make hspace applied to only right side?

```
<img src="/images/pic.jpg" hspace="20" align="left" alt="Tim Ng, Chief Economic Advisor, The Treasury">
```

I can not use margin-right on its own as i am coding a HTML newsletter and margin/padding doesn't work with outlook etc.

Thanks!

Comment: A good practice is to add padding to the `td` instead, give that a try